# How do I get all the versions of a record in orientdb

Tags: orientdb

I have a set of data that gets refreshed at regular interval. Rather than having them in a flat record with timestamp and creating a new record for every update, I am trying to see if I can use the versioning built into orientdb. But, is there a way to query for all or subset of the versions of a record and is there any scale/performance limitations of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrientDB's versioning is to manage MVCC, so old versions are not kept in database. You can do this by writing a hook, called after updates -- onAfterUpdate() method-- saving old versions somewhere.